# MySQL connection is lost while running another Python script from my own with os.system()

Tags: python, mysql, flask, os.system

I have to call my friend's Python script which contains lots of queries from my own Python code. When the script is run independently by him, SQL connection is fine and expected output was given. But When I use os.system(cmd), MySQL connection was lost always for the last query.

cmd = 'python3 home/fin/script.py arg'

I tried to put delay after os.system(cmd), with time.sleep(60). But it seems the issue is the command was executed so fast that it lost SQL connection only for the last SQL query, before Connection can be closed.

Comment: I appreciate that this might not be a direct answer to your question (hence it being a comment!), but is there a reason you can't import your friends script and call the function from your code, rather than using os.system()? Generally speaking, this would be the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks @JosephRedfern for the comment. We still use os.system(), but the script is divided to more than one now. So I have to do one more os.system() . It works